# Google Play Services incompatibility

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I've been using google's fused location services on my app for location tracking. I use Android studio and it's gradle build system. Recently I have discovered a big issue with google's location services.

My gradle build file contained this dependency: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+`. So when I rebuilt my project, Android studio downloaded the latest version for google play services, namely 5.2.08. HOWEVER my device (Samsung Galaxy S4) only has the 5.0.89 version. And apparently these two versions are not compatible, I get this error : `Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089038`. I cannot update google play services on my device. It states that it is up to date (5.0.89).

Using [this solution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880#c65) I managed to get the tracking system working, but it won't work on another device I own (a W8L device), which has another version of google play services: 5.0.84.

It seems this is not an uncommon thing to happen with google. How can I fix this for any devices out there, and make sure that google doesn't mess up my app.

Answer (score 11):

Same thing is happening here, i solved by changing the play services version at gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

They probably released a new version but the roll out haven't arrived in our devices yet.

Comment: Yes, I solved it the same way but, I don't think it's the right solution considering that it doesn't work on another device that has google play services 5.0.84.

Comment: And yes, they have probably released a new version but the roll out hasn't arrived in our devices, but ...should that happen? I mean I could have released my app in a non-functional condition without even knowing. One day it works, the next it doesn't. That's not cool, Google!

Comment: It seems like I am the only one who still got this problem. I also changed the gradle to 5.0.89 but I still get the message: "Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089038", why is 5208000 still expected although i've declared 5.0.89?

Comment: Iam new to studio.Does this means that i have to change Google Play Service version in build.gradle every time?